# Unable to connect to Mongo Community server on OS X Catalina

Tags: mac-osx, mongodb

After migrating my old MacBook Pro to a new machine via the Migration Assistant, I am unable to connect to MongoDB.

I re-installed it via Homebrew, and when I run:

```
brew services start mongodb-community
```

Terminal states that the service started, however, when I run: `mongo`

I get this error:

```
MongoDB shell version v3.4.9
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2020-04-09T09:20:02.419-0400 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2020-04-09T09:20:02.419-0400 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:237:13
```

I was following this guide on Medium: https://medium.com/better-programming/installing-mongodb-on-macos-catalina-aab1cbe0c836

to re-install MongoDB. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you reinstall `brew` after migration? I had lots of problems after upgrade to Catalina. However on fresh Catalina (and `brew` default installation) I:

1. `brew tap mongodb/brew`
2. `brew install mongodb-community`
3. `brew services start mongodb-community`
4. `==> Successfully started`mongodb-community`

You can try to:

1. download Xcode command line
2. restart
3. clear `cellar` folder and `brew cache`
4. `brew tap mongodb/brew`

or full brew reinstall and follow 1-4.

Comment: I get exactly the same error, even after completely un-installing Homebrew, re-installing Homebrew and MongoDB Community. It will start the server, but not allow me to connect.

Comment: Well, it's strange, but after restarting my Mac and then restarting the service, I was able to connect.

Comment: That's why they call it "Crapalina" ;)